# IONIC: How can i access a file in assets folder?

Tags: file, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a problem when I try access a file where is project's assets folder. I can't access it.

Can you help me ?

My ts is:

```
var fileName = "assets/Atiye.mp4";
this.file.checkFile(this.file.applicationStorageDirectory, fileName)
.then((result) => {
alert('file exists :' + result);
},(error)=>{
alert('error : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

The directory is like that:

[image]

and error is :

[image]

Comment: no need to use file plugin cause you can use directly on html like `./assets/videos/Atiye.mp4`

Comment: ` this.videoPlayer.play('./assets/Atiye.mp4').then(() => {
            alert('video completed');
          }).catch(err => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
          });`  i want to access like this but the video player doesnt start video.

Comment: @Mustafa UYSAL May I know, show pictures in assets folder without any problems??

Comment: `VideoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/assets/video/Atiye.mp4");` try it in this way.

Comment: not gonna work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your TypeScript file located?
I assume it is in the /app folder.

Therefore (even if I don't think that you can directly play the video) to get to your file you should do:

```
var fileName = "../assets/Atiye.mp4";
```